# F# recursion behavior

Tags: recursion, f#

I recently started learning F# and because I am quite new to most of the functional concepts I tend to want to write small examples for myself and check my premises with the results of the test.

Now I can't seem to be able to understand the result of the following code and why it behaves as such. The use case: I roll four six sides dice and only return their total when their sum is greater than 20.

This is my code:

```
let rnd = System.Random()
let d6 () = rnd.Next(1, 7)
let rec foo () =
    // create a list of 4 d6 throws and print out the list
    let numbers = seq { for i in 1 .. 4 -> d6() }
    numbers |> Seq.iter( fun n -> printf "%i " n )
    printfn "\n"

    // sum the list and return the sum only when the sum is greater than 20
    let total = numbers |> Seq.sum
    match total with
    | n when n < 21 -> foo ()
    | _ -> total
```

Now when you run this you will find that this will eventually return a number greater than 20.

When you look at the output you will find that it did not print out the last list of numbers and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sequences are lazily evaluated and are not cached. What happens here is that you have a sequence *with a side effect* that's evaluated multiple times.

First evaluation yields first sequence of random numbers:

```
numbers |> Seq.iter( fun n -> printf "%i " n )
```

The second call runs the evaluation *again*, producing completely different sequence:

```
let total = numbers |> Seq.sum
```

What you need to do if you want to keep the first evaluation around to run through it multiple times is either materialize the sequence or cache it:

```
// create a list directly
let numbers = [ for i in 1 .. 4 -> d6() ] 
// or create a list from sequence
let numbers = seq { for i in 1 .. 4 -> d6() } |> List.ofSeq
// or cache the sequence
let numbers = seq { for i in 1 .. 4 -> d6() } |> Seq.cache
```